# Prototype.js error - 'undefined' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am getting following error in Prototype.js

```
'undefined' is null or not an object line 5557 char 5
```

which is this:

```
var respondersForEvent = registry.get(eventName);
    if (Object.isUndefined(respondersForEvent)) {
      respondersForEvent = [];
      registry.set(eventName, respondersForEvent);
    }
```

How can i fix this?

Here is the code giving error:

```
Event.observe(window, "load", function () { 
    Event.observe("query", "keypress", function (e) { 
        if (e.keyCode == Event.KEY_RETURN) { 
            search(); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

It says error is on keypress.

Comment: It has probably nothing to do with Prototype, but with your code that is using it.

Comment: Yes, could we see the code that calls an prototype-method, which then generates this error?

Comment: Placing `isUndefined` on `Object` doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: @ChaosPandion well if that's the case I suggest you should avoid an overwhelming feeling of "unrightness" and stay away from the Prototype documentation :-) (Lots of people agree with you; I'm ambivalent.)

Comment: @Pointy - Well considering `undefined` is a fundamental type of ECMAScript it seems a bit random to associate it specifically with the `Object` constructor.

Comment: I agree; that seems like an odd place to put the functionality, especially when the library has already claimed the global "$" symbol.

Comment: It's even more odd given that it doesn't save a single character over the identically equivalent typeof <whatever> == 'undefined', which is faster to boot (operator vs function call).

Comment: Browser? I've had similar errors in IE, and all is hunky-dory on everything else.

Comment: Here is the code which is giving error:                             Event.observe(window, "load", function () { 
Event.observe("query", "keypress", function (e) { 
if (e.keyCode == Event.KEY_RETURN) { 
search(); 
} 
}); 
});

Comment: If you have google chrome or firebug add "console.log(e);" after function(e) { ... and look in the javascript console to see if your handler executes or not and what is in e.

Comment: Can you confirm that `registry` exists? Which line, specifically, is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an element with the ID "query"? Note that it cannot just have a `name` attribute—for the code you have provided, it must have "query" as the `id` attribute. A valid example would be:

```
<input type="text" id="query" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, look for duplicate javascript code. In my case I had included the mini search form of Magento and its related javascript twice:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form_new', 'search', '<?php echo $this->__('Search entire store here...') ?>');
searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
//]]>
</script>
```

Hope this help anyone with same problem.

Comment: Hai don't give search in the parameter use below php code to get the search box name and id dynamically `<?php echo $this->helper('catalogSearch')->getQueryParamName() ?>` And make sure u have the both id and the name information for the search box.